# Howto create a NavBar which changes color according to the active link in reactjsx?

Tags: reactjs, navbar, jsx

My code looks like following:

```
  return (
    <Container>
      <div>
        <Router>
          <div className='menuStyle'>
            <Link to="/" id="about" data-cy="about">about</Link>{' '}
            <Link to="/ballrooms" id="home" data-cy="home" >ballrooms</Link>{' '}
            <Link to="/schools" id="schools" data-cy="schools">schools</Link>{' '}
            <Link to="/videos" id="videos" data-cy="videos">videos</Link>{' '}
            <Link to="/calendars" id="calendars" data-cy="calendars">calendar</Link>{' '}
            {' <'}{user.username}> logged in {' '}
            <button data-cy="logout" onClick={handleLogout}>logout</button>
          </div> ....
```

Well, this is just a little part, but here is where  I want to change colour according to active link. I know that there are many ways, but the ones I think I could get working are so much of work that there must be easier way. I have used primarily semantic ui in this app.

The css menuStyle I used is just simple:

```
.menuStyle {
  padding-top: 10;
  background: lightgray;
  margin-bottom: 5;
}
```

*I suppose there **must be good and simpler way** to get active navbar with changing color / emphasis, but I didn't get one working.*

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the `NavLink` component from Router.  Similar to `Link`, but can accept styling.  Check it out:  [Using the Link and NavLink Components to Navigate to a Route](https://www.codementor.io/@packt/using-the-link-and-navlink-components-to-navigate-to-a-route-rieqipp42)

Comment: It is customary that when someone posts an answer that is helpful, you should mark it as the answer and potentially upvote it.  Might you help me get some of these sweet internet points kind friend?

Comment: @laurik Why do not accept the answer if it is correct?

Comment: Sorry, I not so used yet with the practices.